# How to parse html of a website which using CloudFlare CDN?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am trying to parse a website HTML data with **simple_html_dom.php** Library.

The problem here is, The website that I am trying to parse is showing **CloudFlare** CDN Protection window before getting in to the page. So, I can't get into the page and parse the Html Data.
[image: CloudFlare CDN Window for DDOS Protection]

Here I am posting the code which I used to parse the Html data of the website.

```
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = @file_get_html($content);
echo $html;
```

Comment: And what is your question? If you want to parse the HTML given by Cloudflare, just do it. If you want to parse the **real** HTML provided by the page under CDN protection, parse the Cloudflare page, trigger the redirect and parse again

Comment: that would be rather difficult if not _impossible_ due to the fact it need a proper browser that runs javascript. the thing that you might consider is, using [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) which is nodejs.. as far as i am aware, there is no browser-backed php library yet.. [i might be wrong](https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs)..

Comment: @NicoHaase Actually I want to parse the data after the bypass by CloudFlare but while using the `$html = @file_get_html($content);` it just stuck on the CloudFlare bypassing page. Can't access it. Itried multiple time access but the result is same.

Comment: You won't likely get past it with phantomjs or selenium either. I'd be very surprised if someone posted a working solution here.